# Extract a type from extended interface

Tags: typescript

I need to extract a type that passed but was never used as a member.

```
// an interface has a generic input type but does not explicitly use it
interface Box<Type> {
  name: string,
}

// there is some interface that extends Box
interface NumberBox extends Box<number> {
  
}

// I need to get the type "number" from "NumberBox" and save into a new type
// something like this
// type ContainType = get(NumberBox); // should return number
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure you can't do this (but I've been wrong about that with TypeScript before :-) ). If you describe what you want it for, we might be able to suggest an alternative way to achieve it.

Comment: Unused type parameters generally don't matter to type compatibility, so they are ignored. You can use a conditional type to etxract the box type if it is used in `Box` (in any capacity) but not otherwise: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsAeAeAKgTwAcIA+ZAbwChlkQ4BbCALmQGcwpQBzAGmuQD6ANxYFiyAPQTkAWQCu7ZBEzB2lAL6VQkWIhQA5OfQBG0DJiWZIIACas0WbCCOmoZcpspgiKc2Ih4ZAC8yLiW1nYOOKAw0MgAqiQA-AnILCAQQtBePsgAwujgcKD+yCF+PtiGJmZYJADcQA